# Clojure Loop Insert

Tags: loops, clojure

So, i have a map like this

```
Defn invoice
{:productid ["001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010"]
:weight ["100" "200" "100" "100" "100" "100" "100" "100" "100" "100"]
:quantity ["1" "2" "3" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"]
:price ["25" "20" "40" "100" "35" "55" "28" "70" "20" "20"]
:shipping "5"
```

and i'm trying to filter the data insert it into the database

```
(defn insert-sales [invoice]
  (sql/with-connection
db
(sql/insert-values
 :salest
 [:salesid :productid :weight :quantity :price :shipping]
[123
(filter #(> (Integer. (first %)) 0) (map vector (sample :quantity) (sample :productid)))
(filter #(> (Integer. (first %)) 0) (map vector (sample :quantity) (sample :weight)))
(filter #(> (Integer. (first %)) 0) (map vector (sample :quantity)))
(filter #(> (integer. (first %)) 0) (map vector (sample :quantity) (sample :price)))
(map read-string (sample :shipping))])))
```

but i'm kinda stuck in making the loop function so the data that i insert is like
["123" "001" "100" "1" "25" "5"]
["123" "002" "200" "2" "20" "5"]..etc

what loop condition that should i use to make it loop ?

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems like the way you're modeling your data is adding a lot of complexity, would modeling your invoice something like this help:

```
(def invoice
  {:sales
   [{:product-id "001" :weight "100" :quanitiy 1 :price 25}
    {:product-id "002" :weight "100" :quanitiy 2 :price 20}
    {:product-id "003" :weight "100" :quanitiy 3 :price 35}
    {:product-id "004" :weight "100" :quanitiy 1 :price 5}]
   :shipping "5"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(map vector (repeat 123) 
            (:producid sample)
            ... 
            (repeat (:shipping sample))
```

Comment: or `(apply map vector ((juxt (constantly 123) :productid :weight :quantity :price (comp repeat :shipping)) sample))`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you want to look at [interleave](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/interleave) function? But if you can do it then I agree with @firthh - you should change your data structure...